# explain the pointers to pointers issue

Tags: c

I'm new into C and I'm trying to get a grip on pointers. I came across this expression

```
char *foo = *(char **)bar;
```

what exactly is going on? I understand that * is pointer ** is pointer to pointer, but I don't really get what is `*(char **)bar`

edit:
worth to mention that bar is declared as const void *bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginners and experts alike can benefit from getting the basics really solid.

- A "*variable* of type t" is a storage location which can be used to store or fetch a *value* of type t.
- A "*pointer* to t" is a *value*.
- Applying the dereferencing operator `*` to a "pointer to t" produces a "variable of type t".

So what have we got?

```
void *bar = whatever;
char *foo = *(char **)bar;
```

- `bar` is a variable of type "pointer to void".
- `foo` is a variable of type "pointer to char".
- casting `bar` to `char**` reads the variable `bar` and fetches a value of type "pointer to void". That value is then converted into a value of type "pointer to pointer to char".
- Dereferencing that value produces a variable of type "pointer to char".
- The value of that variable is then fetched, and the value is assigned to variable `foo`.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes thanks, bar in this case was of type void* hence the cast to char**

Answer (score 8):

```
*(char**)bar;
```

Cast `bar` to a pointer to pointer to `char` and dereference, which results in a pointer to `char` (i.e., a `char*`).

Remember that pointers are merely indirection.  When you dereference a pointer you "drop a star", i.e.:

```
char ***p = ...;
p    -> char***
*p   -> char**
**p  -> char*
***p -> char
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type `bar` is without the cast, but here goes:

`bar` is being cast into a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

The `*` before the `(char **)` is "dereferencing" the value to its right. In this case, it is returning the `char *` pointer held in the location pointer to by `bar`.

The result of the "dereferencing" is a `char *` -- pointer to a character -- which is assigned to the `foo` variable of the same type.