# What does this do exactly? [*(char*)p1]

Tags: c, pointers, char, void

I am not used to pointers because I started learning Pascal in high school and now I am upgrading myself to C. My request would be to explain me what should I think when I see something like this `[*(char*)p1]`. Don't be shy writing me quite a few lines :)

Thank you.

P.S. p1 is a `const void *`. To be more accurate.

Comment: I'd say, cast `p1` to `char*` and dereference it (grab the value at that address). The value is being used as an array index `[ ]`.

Comment: Before `[` in `[*(char*)p1]` there should be some array name. `[*(char*)p1]` alone will be a compiler error as @[Damon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21045657/1673391) also mentioned.

Comment: My answer to this question might help you understand this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034253/explain-the-pointers-to-pointers-issue/21034375#21034375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void *p1;`// pointer to void or generic pointer; might be used when you want to be flexible about the data type

`(char*)p1;` //typecast to a char pointer; you address the memory locatuion pointed to by P1 as char

`*(char*)p1;` //the value at the location pointed to by p1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `[*(char*)p1]` is an array designator, `(char*)` is used to cast `p1` to make `p1` `char *` type. Then `*` is used to dereference it to use value at the address (`p1` points to) as index to some array.

Answer (score 1):

`[*(char*)p1]` is somewhat incomplete, there needs to be a variable name in front of it for the array subscription to make sense, such as for example `foo[*(char*)p1]`.

In that case, it means:

- convert p1 to pointer-to-char
- dereference this pointer (giving a `char` value)
- use this value as index to look up in an array

Note that using a `char` as index will make most compilers unhappy and cause it to emit a warning. That is because most often when a `char` is used as an index, it happens by error, not by intent, and also because it is implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned (so it is inherently non-portable, and you may end up indexing out of bounds by accident, if you assume the wrong one).

Comment: Damon if I casts to `unsigned char*` and then derefrences then it doesn't gives warning where with `char*` and `-wall`  compiler emits warning. Any comment? I am using GCC

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Casting to `unsigned char*` is **much** safer because then it's well-defined whether or not it is signed (i.e. it is not), and you cannot accidentially use e.g. index `-56` when you _really_ meant to use `200`. This is one nasty thing that could otherwise for example happen with GCC where `char` equals `signed char`. So the compiler doesn't warn any more because apart from the risk of overflowing, it's pretty safe and well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

1. `(char*)p1` is a typecast. This means, for this statement, we're treating `p1` as a pointer to a character.
2. `*(char*)p1` dereferences `p1`, interpreting it as a `char` type due to the typecast `(char*)`. A pointer points to a memory location, and dereferencing that pointer returns the value at the location in memory `p1` points to.
3. `[*(char*)p1]` ... Array access? is this a snippet from something larger?

This `void*` to `someOtherType*` conversion is common in C code, because [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/), used to allocate memory dynamically, returns `void*`.